# Error while running a BCP command in the SQL JOB

Tags: sql-server, bcp, sql-job

I am trying to run a BCP command and getting below error, googled a lot but did not really find any answer, can someone please help?

This is the error on top:

> Error xp_cmdshell on bcp

Error on bottom:

> No error message found in xp_cmdshell output [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error
>   50000).  The step failed

Comment: Do you have an error file configured on your bcp command?

Comment: I am not sure as i am just doing this for my colleague in his absence